# WMI CommandLineEventConsumer does not working

Tags: powershell, wmi

Please help me with WMI.
I need to start some powershell after windows logon.

Here is my code:

```
$filterName='MyLogonFilter2';
$consumerName='MyCommandLineEventConsumer2';

#Creating a new event filter
$filterResult = Set-WmiInstance -Computername $env:COMPUTERNAME -Namespace 'root\subscription' -Class __EventFilter -Arguments  @{Name = $filterName; EventNamespace = 'root\CIMV2'; QueryLanguage = 'WQL'; Query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 30 where targetInstance isa 'Win32_LogonSession'"}

#Creating a consumer
$consumerResult = Set-WmiInstance -Computername $env:COMPUTERNAME -Namespace 'root\subscription' -Class CommandLineEventConsumer -Arguments @{Name = $consumerName; ExecutablePath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"; CommandLineTemplate = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -C `"Get-Date|Out-File C:/time.txt`""}

#Creating a binging
Set-WmiInstance -Computername $env:COMPUTERNAME -Namespace 'root\subscription' -Class __FilterToConsumerBinding -Arguments @{Filter = $filterResult; Consumer = $consumerResult} |  out-null
```

Nothing is working =(

I see my Filter, Consumer and Binder, but nothing is runing and the file time.txt is not creating...
Please help me!

Comment: Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventFilter

Comment: Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventConsumer

Comment: Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __FilterToConsumerBinding

Comment: You should elaborate on what *nothing* means. What are you doing to run this? GPO? Run key in Local Machine? Startup folder for User? Are you getting errors?

Comment: I need to create file C:\time.txt with date and time. (after user log on)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your filter name space is incorrect. It should be root\cimv2